# The MIDI is not recognized

Tags: midi

I have a laptop ASUS X555LJ with UBUNTU 14.04 LTS. I would like to connect the elettronic keyboard M-AUDIO KeyStudio 49 to UBUNTU. The connection is from USB. Ubuntu does not Recognize The MIDI. Some help please.

Comment: Does it show up in the output of `lsusb`? In `/proc/asound/cards`?

Comment: I have done the two outputs, maybe you can help me understand the meaning: " https://pastebin.com/j4KWHuAV " I don't know why the second line of comand - /proc/asound/cards - is denied to me.

Comment: The second is not a command but a file. But the device does not even show up in `lsusb`, so this is probably not a driver problem. Try another USB port, or another USB cable, or check if it shows up on another computer.

Comment: I tried another USB cable, nothing is canged. I checked if it Shows up on another computer, it showed up.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with this laptop, or its software. (Isn't 14.04 kind of out of date?)